# Regex for allowing 4 numbers(of any length) in input field

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for javascript validation which allows to input four numbers of any length separated by comma.

For example:

```
12,111,3455556666,1
```

or

```
40,01,9,19877666666
```

I am using a regex below:

```
/^\d(,\d){0,3}/
```

But it is not working as required.

Could anybody help me in forming the correct regex pattern?

Comment: `\d` only matches a single digit. You need some kind of quantifier there.

Comment: *4 numbers of any length*. Its a bit confusing. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: How about `/^\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+$/`?

Comment: @MohammadUsman, like-  21,33333333,10,13433

Comment: You need `/^\d+(?:,\d+){0,3}$/` to match 1 to 4 digit chunks separated with a comma.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I guess it should be `{3}` instead of `{0,3}` as OP wants 4 numbers exactly and not a range?

Comment: @MohammadUsman I do not see the *exactly* bit. Anyway, the question is unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew may be, may be :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, acc. to your regex I am not able to enter even single comma, 4 numbers so 3 commas should be allowed, could you check it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Acc. to your regex 122222,  is showing no match in regex tester,

Comment: It does match - https://regex101.com/r/u492eE/1. Your main concern is the *code*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, exactly as per your link also, if I am entering comma after one value it is not showing as match until and unless another number is typed, I want alteast til 3 commas it should show as match eg.1222222, and 
1222222,1222222, and
1222222,1222222,1222222,

Comment: Probably, `^\d+(?:,\d*){0,3}$` will work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes this one is working.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^\d+(?:,\d*){0,3}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u492eE/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d*){0,3}` - 0 to 3 occurrences of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ["1222222", "1222222,1222222", "1222222,1222222,1222222,", "1222222,1222222,1222222,1222222", "1222222,1222222,1222222,1222222,1222222,1222222"];
var rx = /^\d+(?:,\d*){0,3}$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
/^(\d{1,},){3}\d{1,}$/
```

The first three digits followed by comma, then the last digit and every `\d` can be of length one or more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
`/^(\d+,){0,3}\d+/`
This shuold match three sequences of multiple digits followed by comma, and four number after them.